# How to call a MS Access database macro from C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

I just wanted to know whether it's possible to invoke a module function or a macro in MS Access database from outside. Using C#

Thanks

Comment: While it's possible to do it, it's not necessarily advisable. If you're operating on data, doing data manipulation, then you really should just issue the SQL commands to do the updates, rather than trying to automate Access.

Comment: I'm working on porting an existing legacy project and we simply don't have the time to rewrite all of the custom reports, subqueries, macros, and other logic tangled up in there. Invoking the internal code may be the only way to start the project for the time being. It's an unfortunate transition path when someone has made a serious commitment to MS Access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You can run macros.

This [Article](https://web.archive.org/web/20110605040645/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306683) (only available via archive.org) shows everything you need.