# How to pass variables from C# to VBA (access)

Tags: c#, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a searchable access database that contains searchable PDF documents in an attachment field. At the moment, a user would add a PDF to the attachment box, then fill in the searchable fields manually

I would like to expedite the process by calling a C# program to pull out the info I need (Name, Product, ect.) from within access and pass the strings and integers to VBA which would then fill the text boxes. I have never transferred variables from one language to another. How would I go about doing this?

edit: further elaboration on the proposed answer to my question. The link answers how to invoke a module in access from outside, I'm asking how to pass values from a program invoked INSIDE access. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a MS Access database macro from C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058988/how-to-call-a-ms-access-database-macro-from-c-sharp)

Comment: Open the MDB directly using the OLEDB driver, and place the data in directly.

Comment: @Ben I don't follow. I haven't done anything like this before. Do you mind explaining a bit more in depth?
edit: I also realize that my previous comment was deleted. I don't know why because I thought I was being friendly, but I'm guessing it came across badly. Sorry

Comment: Why are you using C#? Is this a pre-existing C# program? If not, why not use VBA which is built in to Access? In other words, what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I did some research and I read that VBA couldn't read PDF so I thought C# would be good. As for the goal, I want to search the PDF for the values I want (most are strings) and put those in my table along side the document

Comment: OK so you want to extract the values from the PDF, and you have identified C# components which can do this, and you want to call them from VBA. So the answer is you need to "call dotnet object from vba". You need COM Interop.