# c# read/edit accdb macro

Tags: c#, ms-access, office-interop

I am trying to access the macros inside of an Access database (accdb).

I tried using:

```cs
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;

...

DBEngine dbe = new DBEngine();
Database ac = dbe.OpenDatabase(fileName);
```

I found a `container["Scripts"]` that had a `document["Macro1"]` which is my target. I am struggling to access the contents of the document. I also question if the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao` is the best reference for what I am trying to achieve.

What is the best way to view the content of the macros and modules?

Comment: have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058988/how-to-call-a-ms-access-database-macro-from-c-sharp)

Comment: That is to run a macro using the doCmd method. I am wanting access to the code and not just access the db commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the DAO part, it's not needed in this case. Macros are project specific, so in order to get them all, you would need to loop through your projects. In my example, i just have one project.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;

namespace Sandbox48
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application oAccess = null;
            string savePath = @"C:\macros\";
            oAccess = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Application();

            // Open a database in exclusive mode:
            oAccess.OpenCurrentDatabase(
               @"", //filepath
               true //Exclusive
               );

            var allMacros = oAccess.CurrentProject.AllMacros;

            foreach(var macro in allMacros)
            {
                var fullMacro = (AccessObject)macro;
                Console.WriteLine(fullMacro.Name);

                oAccess.SaveAsText(AcObjectType.acMacro, fullMacro.FullName, $"{savePath}{ fullMacro.Name}.txt");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought that the DAO might be going into a deeper reference than required. The office.interop docs that I have found online do not seem to be very comprehensive. Are you aware of any location with decent docs?

Comment: Also, I would use the oAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase() command to release the object. It keeps an instance open in memory.